# Get windows version from git bash

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

I was trying to determine the type of windows10 install (home vs pro) in a git-bash shell script using:

```
if [[ ! $(wmic os get caption) = *"Home"* ]];then
    echo "Not using windows home"
fi
```

However a french user just reported a bug where the windows version was returned in the local language, in this case "Microsoft Windows 10 Famille". Other than translating "Home" into every language, is there a better way to determine if the script is running on home vs pro in the face of multiple languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one solution i have found is to look for the existence of bitlocker as feature that exists on windows pro and not on windows home.

```
if [[ ! -f /c/Windows/System32/BitLockerWizard.exe ]];then 
    echo "On windows home"
fi
```